# How to Parse Boolean Search Queries

Tags: parsing, boolean-expression

I need to parse a search query with boolean parameters.  For example, if I have the query

`(Mexico or Peru) and ((Air and Wind) or (Big and Little))`

I want to create several sub-queries based on the operators. So, this query will give me the following sub queries

Mexico , Air, Wind
Mexico , Big , Little
Peru, Air , Wind
Peru, Big , Little

Does anyone have an idea about an algorithm I could use or maybe a library that would help me with that?

Thank you!

Comment: What language? You need to tell us a little more :)

Comment: Language makes a big difference. Many databases have full-text search capabilities that can parse the query automatically.